# python webscraper addressing divs with no class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some data from Liquipedia and I'm having trouble in getting the script to work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/S1mple'

#empty_array

player_data = []

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

data = soup.find('div', class_='fo-nttax-infobox')

for player_data in data.find_all('div', attrs={'class': None}):
    print(player_data)
```

The print command returns all sets of data, but ideally, I would only want to have it filled with the "Player Information" box on this page https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/S1mple.

I have tried several ways which didn't work. My main problem seems to be that the information contained there doesn't belong to any particular div class that I can address. How do I go about creating an object that includes all that data in two columns?

I'm aware that I should normally use the WikiMedia API, however I'm trying to familiarize with this method first as part of my learning path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no expected output, this just points in a direction - Select your elements sibling by class and use `find_next_sibling('div')`:

```
dict( (e.text, e.find_next_sibling('div').text) for e in soup.select('.infobox-description'))
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/S1mple'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')

data = dict( (e.text, e.find_next_sibling('div').text) for e in soup.select('.infobox-description')) 

print(data)
```

##### Output

```
{'Name:': 'Олександр Олегович Костилєв',
 'Romanized Name:': 'Oleksandr Oleghovych Kostyljev',
 'Nationality:': '\xa0Ukraine',
 'Born:': 'October  2, 1997 (age\xa025)',
 'Status:': 'Active',
 'Years Active (Player):': '2013 – Present',
 'Role:': 'AWPer',
 'Team:': 'Natus Vincere',
 'Nicknames:': 'The Undertaker',
 'Approx. Total Winnings:': '$1,733,186',
 'Games:': 'Global Offensive'}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a follow-up question, when trying to recreate the code, how would I go about receiving that output from your example? It doesn't work for the print(dict) command.

Comment: wrap the dict comprehension in the print or assign it to a variable and print these, check the edit.

Comment: Thanks, saw your edit. Works like a charm!

Comment: Just one more follow-up, since the nickname (in this case s1mple) is not part of the infobox, how would I go about including that into the dict as well?

Comment: after creating dict simply append the information e.g. from url  `data['nickname'] = url.split('/')[-1]` or first `h1`, ...